# What is the "U\+[0-9A-F]{4,6}" notation for specifying a Unicode character called?

Tags: unicode, terminology

What is the name of this notation? For example, if I want to say of the character U+2603 SNOWMAN,

> The _____ of the Snowman character is "U+2603".

what should replace the _____ to make the statement accurate (but would *not* make it accurate if instead of literally "U+2603" it said something else, like "2603" or "9731")?

The Wikipedia page for Unicode describes the convention of writing U+ and then some hexadecimal digits, without giving it a name.

Comment: Unicode names many things, except this notation :)  http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/appA.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation has no official name. The [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/), v. 7, says in clause 2.4:

> When referring to code points in the Unicode Standard, the usual
>   practice is to refer to them by their numeric value expressed in
>   hexadecimal, with a “U+” prefix. (See Appendix A, Notational
>   Conventions.)

Appendix A says:

> In running text, an individual Unicode code point is expressed as U+*n*,
>   where *n* is four to six hexadecimal digits, using the digits 0–9 and
>   uppercase letters A–F (for 10 through 15, respectively). Leading zeros
>   are omitted, unless the code point would have fewer than four
>   hexadecimal digits—for example, U+0001, U+0012, U+0123, U+1234,
>   U+12345, U+102345.
>
> - U+0416 is the Unicode code point for the character named cyrillic capital letter zhe.
>
> The U+ may be omitted for
>   brevity in tables or when denoting ranges.

So the thing closest to an official name would be “U+*n* notation”. But it isn’t given as a name; it’s just part of a description, with *n* being a placeholder.

In the notation, the “U+” part just informs and manifests that the following digits are to be interpreted as a code point in the hexadecimal notation. So you can say “The code point of the Snowman character is 2603 in hexadecimal” or “The code point of the Snowman character is U+2603”.

There is seldom any need to distinguish between the notations 2603 and U+2603. You just use whichever is more suitable on practical grounds, and explain it if necessary. But here’s an example of a case where a distinction needs to made and how it can be made: In Microsoft Office Word, you can enter a Unicode character by entering its code number in hexadecimal and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>; however, if the preceding character is a letter A–F, a–f, X, or x or a digit 0–9, you need to precede the code number by the two characters “U+” or “u+”. (Note that any name for the notation would not help much, especially since no name is generally known and understood.)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the term that would fill in the blank is [*code point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point):

> The code point of the Snowman character is "U+2603".

This term is first used in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Origin_and_development) of the Wikipedia article for Unicode:

> In text processing, Unicode takes the role of providing a unique *code point*—a number, not a glyph—for each character.

And the connection between it and the "U+" notation is made [a little further down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology):

> Normally a Unicode code point is referred to by writing "U+" followed by its hexadecimal number. For code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), four digits are used (e.g. U+0058 for the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X); for code points outside the BMP, five or six digits are used, as required (e.g. U+E0001 for the character LANGUAGE TAG and U+10FFFD for the character PRIVATE USE CHARACTER-10FFFD).

However, the notation itself doesn't have a name, probably because it doesn't need one. It's just a way of representing a code point in writing. The only documents I can find on the Web that make a reference to the notation simply call it "the U+nnnn notation" or something similar. Even the Unicode spec makes no direct reference to the notation; it simply uses it when referring to a code point.

If "U+2603" were "2603" instead, then I would probably say:

> The Unicode hexadecimal value of the Snowman character is 2603.

Likewise for "9731":

> The Unicode decimal value of the Snowman character is 9731.